# How to switch the url of my git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a local directory which has been previously configure with a git repository and hosted on a service called BitBucket.

Now I made a repository in GitHub and want to update the local reference to that, but I got this error:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/iPhoneBusinessPlan.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2:BusinessPlan alexgenadinik$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://genadinik@bitbucket.org/genadinik/ios_business_app.git'
```

And the new repository is in this url:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/iPhoneBusinessPlan.git
```

Any idea how I can switch the local reference to the github url?

Comment: Issue a `git remote remove origin` first

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just remove the origin first:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/genadinik/iPhoneBusinessPlan.git
```

**Edit** if you are doing a repository from scratch from existing sources, after switching remotes, then you could then do:

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "init"
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you - and after that? Do I do commit and push?

Comment: I just tried to do a commit, but got error: git commit -m "first commit"
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: edited my answer, though your second question is out-of-scope of this particular stackoverflow question.. you might consider opening a new question if you can't solve your new issue

Comment: I a still not getting the desired behavior...first I do this: git commit -m "first commit"
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: And I am not sure what it means for the repo to be clean. Do they mean the local one or the one in github?

Comment: And then this happens: git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a (sub)command to change the URL:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/genadinik/iPhoneBusinessPlan.git
```

This way there's no need to re-fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you - and what follows this command? Can I start committing? I tried to commit and got an error

Comment: Nothing else. You can start comitting and pushing then. To create an empty commit use `git commit -m "first commit" --allow-empty`. Try a `git fetch origin` first, to see if git can connect to the new URL. It should either fetch things or tell you you're up-to-date.